# How to make Update-Manager working 

Tags: 10.04, update-manager, updates

I bought my wife a Laptop and installed ubuntu 10.04 as I was tired to answer all her questions about the stupid windows messages "want to do this and that ..." Of course I advertised Ubuntu as a super stable system and so on.

The amount of questions dropped significantly, however unfortunately the update manager doesn't work. It shows the updates, you tell the machine to install, password, it updates and shows you the same updates you should install. Of course she is teasing me. Upgrade via terminal works. I deinstalled and reinstalled the updatemanager, no change.

Comment: might work if you install the mintupdater

Answer (score 1):

To further reduce messages from Update Manager we have the option to install security updates silently in the background. This is done by choosing *System Administration -> Update Manager -> Settings -> Updates*:

[image]

By selecting *Install security updates without confirmation* all security updates will be downloaded and installed without user interaction.

In case you need to install non-security application's updates tick the appropriate options for *Recommended Updates* or *Unsupported Updates* and let Update Manager *Download all updates in the background*. Then you can manually install these updates at a convenient time.

Though **not recommended** further reducing on update frequency may be acchieved by increasing the *Check for Updates* from *Daily* to *Weekly* or more.